# How to tease out the sampling process of a function on the product of Riesz space and sample space?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, vector-lattices

We have a function $D(Z;\omega):\mathcal{Z}\times\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. $\mathcal{Z}$ is Riesz space, $\Omega$ is sample space. For each given $\omega\in\Omega$, $z$ satisfies the partial order property (this is why they lie in Riesz space). I was wondering how to understand the sampling procedure of $D(Z;\omega)$ from measure-theoretic perspective?

Starting from a simple version, if we don't have $Z$, the function $D(\omega):\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a random variable. We can characterize its sampling process using its probability distribution. But how to generalize this notion to $D(Z;\omega)$?

I am not quite familiar with functional analysis (Some terminology may be used incorrectly). That would be great if someone could recommend some books or materials at any level. Thanks in advance!

---

Updated: I realize that it is a stochastic process in which we replace $t$ with $Z$.